# Simple explanation of exceptions?

Tags: assembly

I have an exam tomorrow and one of the subjects is exceptions in assembly. I have a list of them but I haven't been able to find a simple explanation of what an exception is and when each one happens.

**The exceptions are:**

1. Area violation
2. Division by 0 (this one is obvious)
3. Invalid instruction
4. Invalid address
5. Failings

Any info will be of great help, I only need a general idea of what each one is.

Comment: You mean "access violation"

Comment: Because almost every programming language under the sun has exceptions, you can read the first 100,000 hits on google for 'exceptions' to get an idea of what they are.

Comment: might be, I just translated the list from spanish so there might be some inaccuracies

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Normally the code flows as the instructions goes. So when you read the program, you can see where each instruction follows one after the other. The CPU follows this list. Now an exception, as the name says, interrupts this flow of execution. You already have given some examples. An execpetion occurs whenever something happens that the normal flow of instructions can not continue and it has to be dealt with.
So exceptions are basically a way of notifiying the OS or the programmer that something out of the way happened. This can either be a bug in the code or it can be intentional.

For example, a division by zero is usually a bug. Accessing an invalid pointer can also be a bug, but it can also be a trigger for the OS to swap a memory page in from disk. The program gets halted, the OS makes sure that the page gets loaded and then resets the code to continue as if nothing bad happened.

Exceptions are rather similar to interrupts, because they break the regular flow of the program and have to be serviced and often you don't know when they will exactly happen.

Answer (score 3):

Strictly speaking, the exceptions you're referring to are not in assembly language, but are in the operational behavior of the CPU.

Conceptually speaking, a CPU has a set of state registers, consumes a stream of instructions, and manipulates state according to those instructions. Now, this stream contains instructions that manipulate state (e.g. add 1 to register EAX) and instructions that alter the future instruction stream (e.g. JMP topOfLoop).

An exception is like a jump that is taken implicitly. For example, if the current instruction is DIV and the divisor is zero, then the CPU can abort the instruction and instead jump to a different instruction stream, which is known as the exception handler. This is useful because the exception handler can do things to recover from the bad condition. Also, each instruction can potentially trigger many different kinds of exceptions (memory error, protection error, operand error, mode error, alignment error, etc.), and it would be cumbersome to *explicitly* write instructions to check *all* of these conditions.

Answer (score 0):

You may also look up for [interrupts](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interrupt) in general. These exceptions from the list are just examples of software interrupts.

Answer (score 0):

When the processor cannot continue executing the program normally, basically there is an exception to the ability to run the program.  So it ideally goes to an exception handler, some other code, very similar to an interrupt handler, that is used to handle the exception.  Like an interrupt handler someone has to write that code as well as someone writing the application.  Divide by zero is an obvious one, invalid instruction is as well, when the bit pattern found does not match an instruction (machine code) supported by the processor then the processor cannot continue.  A memory fault, when the memory system is unable to read or write a memory location for some reason (ECC multi bit error for example, or an invalid address).

Not all processors have exceptions, some simply have an interrupt and that is it for "Exceptions to the normal execution of the program"...